# imageRectForBounds not called in NSButtonCell subclass

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

I needed to create a NSButton with both image and title but I didn't like any of the standard positioning methods in cocoa.

I decided to subclass the button cell and override the `-imageRectForBounds:` and `-titleRectForBounds:` to provide my custom positions. The problem is that the `-titleRectForBounds:` method gets called normally but the `-imageRectForBounds:` is not.

The images in the buttons are shown normally so the cell must have a frame to draw the images I just don't know where it gets it from.

The code is really simple. At the moment the only thing I did is to subclass NSButtonCell and override those two methods. Then in IB I choose an NSButton and change its cell class to my custom button cell.

Here is the code:

```
#import "JSButtonCell.h"

@implementation JSButtonCell

- (NSRect)titleRectForBounds:(NSRect)theRect
{
    NSLog(@"Bounds for title");
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromRect(theRect));
    NSRect titleRect = [super titleRectForBounds:theRect];
    NSLog(@"Title rect");
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromRect(titleRect));
    return titleRect;
}

- (NSRect)imageRectForBounds:(NSRect)theRect
{
    NSLog(@"Bounds for image");
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromRect(theRect));
    NSRect imageRect = [super imageRectForBounds:theRect];
    NSLog(@"Image rect");
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromRect(imageRect));
    imageRect.origin.y -= 20;
    return imageRect;
}

@end
```

Comment: Same thing is happening here. Have you ever been able to find out what happened?

Comment: No I'm sorry I just abandoned the approach.

Comment: All right, thanks for letting me know. I'll come back and post the solution - if I ever find one...

Answer (score 2):

With little debugging I understand, that default `NSButtonCell` implementation doesn't calls `drawImage:withFrame:inView:`. Why? I don't find an answer neither on forums nor at the Apple docs (If someone explain - I will be happy :). I was solve this issue by simply override `drawImage:withFrame:inView:` and call `imageRectForBounds:`:

```
- (void)drawImage:(NSImage *)image withFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    [super drawImage:image withFrame:[self imageRectForBounds:frame] inView:controlView];
}
```